# Unattended-Upgrades configuration for custom repo only

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

OS: LMDE 5 (based on Debian 11 Bullseye)

To keep the system tidy, I use separate files to overrides the original distribution/developer configuration files wherever possible. This also prevents problems when the developer makes changes to the original config and keeps my settings safe. etc...

For Unattended-Upgrades, the original configuration of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security";
```

I replaced it with the file **51**unattended-upgrades:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "site=myrepo.example.com"
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security";
```

I thought the entire original section would be replaced with my section and UU would **only** update `myrepo.example.com`. But it turns out that all 4 repositories are active:

```
"site=myrepo.example.com"
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian"
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security"
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security"
```

How can I disable all other repos and only have myrepo active **without changing** the original `50unattended-upgrades`?

Comment: I have a major problem with the equal siign in the first line LMDE 5 is absolutely not equal to Bullseye! It might be based on Debian, but it absolutely is not Debian.

Comment: It was a bit of a "mental shortcut" because the UU issue is identical in LMDE5 and Bullseye. But you're right - the equals sign is not the best designation. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` isn't directly part of the package `unattended-upgrades`. Upgrades of this file are managed by its install scripts through helper tools (mostly `dpkg-maintscript-helper` and `ucf --three-way --debconf-ok` as [seen for example in the `postinst` file](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/2.9.1/debian/postinst#L60)): among other things it checks if the file was altered before replacing it with a new maintainer version (and will usually prompt about this with the default of keeping the altered version). The original reference is safely stored at `/usr/share/unattended-upgrades/50unattended-upgrades`.

Having told all this, options can be:

1. change directly `50unattended-upgrades`: Debian will respect the change and prompt for what to do (with an initial default of "keep changed version") if needed.
2. copy it into an other file (`51unattended-upgrades`) and empty this file (but keep it). As above, Debian will respect the change etc.

Or there's a specific APT-related way for APT configurations:

3. Use specific [`apt.conf(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt.conf.5) syntax to forget a former tree, and then replace it with newer values.

   This is documented in [`apt.conf(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt.conf.5#SYNTAX) (emphases mine):

   > [...] `#clear` is used to erase a part of the configuration tree. The **specified element and all its descendants are erased.** (Note that these
   > lines also need to end with a semicolon.)
   >
   > **The `#clear` command is the only way to delete a list or a complete
   > scope.** **Reopening a scope (or using the syntax described below with an
   > appended ::) will not override previously written entries.** Options can
   > only be overridden by addressing a new value to them - **lists and
   > scopes can**'t **be** overridden, only **cleared**.

   Documentation is a bit scarce. By trial-and-error tests (more easily done on the `needrestart` package's configuration) it's: `#clear Some::Tree;` and also "Directives can only be done at the top level", ie: it must be called on a fully qualified scope outside of any scope, rather than within a scope to be applied on a sub-scope.

So the `51unattended-upgrades` file could start with:

```
#clear Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern;
```

to reset the list to an empty list before repopulating it with what follows in this file. Then it's possible to not have to change `50unattended-upgrades` at all and still use its other default settings if any.

Whatever method 1. 2. or 3. in use, the administrator will still have to check what changes appear between two Debian release version (major) upgrades. Eg: [security repository URL schema had a change between Debian 10 and Debian 11](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading#bullseye-security): this would have had to be adapted manually when (re)defining `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern` after an upgrade from Debian 10 to Debian 11 (doesn't apply for OP's specific case which intends to disallow security upgrades too).

Comment: Please look at my edit. Can this be fixed or am I only left with option 1 and option 2?

Comment: I deleted my edit because I made a syntax error - I typed `site:` instead of `site=`. Now it works beautifully!
StackExchange advises against saying thanks, but my heart tells me otherwise and I can't help myself :) Thanks a lot!